# Maintain drag and drop view position on imageview when pinch and zooming

Tags: android

I'm using a very standard drag and drop implementation in order to drag a pin and position it on top of an image view to point to a particular part of the image:

```
@Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                owner.removeView(view);
                FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) v;
                container.addView(view);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                int a = Math.round((event.getX() - (view.getWidth() / 2)));
                int b = Math.round((event.getY() - (view.getHeight() / 2)));

                lp.setMargins(a,b,0,0);
                view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //Gets actual pixel location on image - currently unused
                float[] point = new float[] {event.getX(), event.getY()};
                Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
                iv.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
                inverse.mapPoints(point);
                float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                point[0] /= density;
                point[1] /= density;
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

The imageview is a zoomable image view (chrisbanes/PhotoView), if the image remains at it's usual 100% scale the coordinates all work as they should and the marker is correctly placed. However if i zoom in on the image, to place the marker on a particular spot for finer control, while getting the right coord when i zoom out the marker does not remain in the same position relative to the image. Simply that of the parent. Please let me know what code you'd like to see (There isn't much else) or if i need to re-explain

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I had the same issue related to Rectangular area on an Image. Can I share the whole code but it is long? You just have to manage code for Rectangular area with that of your Marker. I have used `TouchListener `instead.

Comment: So, you place a pin on the image then you zoom in. After zooming, the pin stays put and does not shift with the image. Is that the issue, or is the problem with placing the pin after zooming? If the former, have you written any code to move the pin within the zoomed view?

Answer (score 0):

I did an application in which the user can touch-move views and also can zoom.

In my case all the ViewGroup (RelativeLayout) that contain several views is zoomable as a whole.

I use onTouch instead of onDrag, internally I save the dimensions in **dp** and to convert from **dp** to **pixels** I multiply by (screen density * a zoomfactor)

Here a method that I call from onTouch ACTION_MOVE , the values of xPxInitial, dpLeftInitial, yPxInitial,  dpTopInitial were previously set in ACTION_DOWN.

```
 @Override
    public boolean moveControl(float xPx, float yPx) {

        int newDpLeft, newDpTop;

        newDpLeft = pixelsToDp((int) (xPx - xPxInitial)) + dpLeftInitial;
        newDpTop = pixelsToDp((int) (yPx - yPxInitial)) + dpTopInitial;

        // Limit for left & top
        if (newDpLeft < 0) newDpLeft = 0;
        if (newDpTop < 0) newDpTop = 0;        


        int oldDpLeft = dpLeft;
        int oldDpTop = dpTop;

        dpLeft = newDpLeft;
        dpTop = newDpTop;
        setDimsFromDps(); 

        // return true is the view is really moved
        return (dpLeft != oldDpLeft || dpTop != oldDpTop);
    }
```

pixelsToDp

```
/// Pixels to DP's ....
    public int pixelsToDp(int pixs) {
        return (int) (pixs / (scrDensity * zoomFactor));
    }
```

setDimsFromDps

```
protected void setDimsFromDps() {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layPar = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        // avoid left & top < 0

        layPar.setMargins(Math.max(dpToPixels(dpLeft), 0), Math.max(dpToPixels(dpTop), 0), 0, 0);
        layPar.width = dpToPixels(dpWidth);
        layPar.height = dpToPixels(dpHeight);


        setLayoutParams(layPar);

    }

Hope it will help
```